# Card.io Scanner Not Working on Samsung Galaxy 6

Tags: card.io

The Card.io scanner does not seem to be working on Samsung Galaxy 6. Is there an update/patch available for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the latest card.io api, it was updated and should be working with Galaxy 6 now.